# Select data of previous month together with current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To make a dashboard I need specific data of past and present records. So what I want to achieve is that all records of the past months that up until now do not have the state 'Accepted', will be added as the number of records for that state.

**Wanted result**

| Number or records | State | Month | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Draft | April | CLR |
| 5 | Withdrawn | April | DPK |
| 3 | Draft | May | CLR |
| 6 | Withdrawn | May | DPK |
| 7 | Draft | June | CLR |
| 10 | Withdrawn | June | DPK |
| 6 | Draft | July | CLR |
| 8 | Withdrawn | July | DPK |

*Option 2*

| Number or records | State | Month | Name | April | May | June | July |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Draft | April | CLR | 2 | 3 | 7 | 6 |
| 5 | Withdrawn | April | DPK | 5 | 6 | 10 | 8 |

There is a table that keeps track of every record and their state. It also records when a state changes. Per month you don't want the records that have the state 'Accepted'.

**Records table 1**

| Name | EndDate | State | ID | StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLR | 21-04-2020 | Draft | 1 | 16-04-2020 |
| DPK | 22-04-2020 | Withdrawn | 2 | 21-04-2020 |
| DPK | 05-04-2020 | Draft | 3 | 18-03-2020 |
| DPK | 06-04-2020 | Withdrawn | 3 | 05-04-2020 |
| CLR | 26-04-2020 | Draft | 4 | 25-04-2020 |
| CLR | 26-04-2020 | Withdrawn | 5 | 24-04-2020 |
| CLR | 26-04-2020 | Withdrawn | 6 | 11-04-2020 |
| CLR | 04-05-2020 | Withdrawn | 4 | 01-05-2020 |
| CLR | 05-05-2020 | Accepted | 4 | 04-05-2020 |

**Table 2** (Holds most recent ID state)

| Name | Date | State | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLR | 21-04-2020 | Draft | 1 |
| DPK | 22-04-2020 | Withdrawn | 2 |
| DPK | 06-04-2020 | Withdrawn | 3 |
| CLR | 26-04-2020 | Withdrawn | 5 |
| CLR | 26-04-2020 | Withdrawn | 6 |
| CLR | 05-05-2020 | Accepted | 4 |

In this table it would show all the record of April in the count for April. But may would have all his own records + the records of April that haven't been accepted yet at this point. ( So all except record ID 4 in may)

The code I have so far works for 1 month back.

```
    SELECT 
        te.name,
        te.State,
        Count(*) AS Number
    FROM 
        Table2 te
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        Table1 wfd
                    WHERE wfd.EndDate = (SELECT MAX(wfd2.EndDate)
                                         FROM Table1 wfd2
                                         WHERE wfd2.Id = wfd.Id
                                         AND (wfd2.StartDate< DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETUTCDATE())
                                         AND (wfd.State NOT IN ('Accepted')))
                                         )
                         ) wf on te.Id = wf.Id
    GROUP BY
        te.Name,
        te.State,
```

Comment: Instead of this query might I suggest using the 'LAG' functionality? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 

Furthermore, you might want to edit your question a little. At least I really don't know what you want help with.

Comment: @Max At the moment I only get 1 month at the time. I want a view that has all the months in one table ( for the past 6 months for example). And i tried LAG before but that didn't work. Cause it will show only april for example. But if a record hasn't been updated since april and the state is still draft, the enddate will still be the same but i want to see that record in july aswell.

Comment: If I understand correctly. You just want to count rows where state is not accepted and group by Name and Month? 

If that is true, I would suggest:

SELECT count(*) AS Number, State, MONTH(Date) as Month, Name
FROM Table 1
WHERE State <> 'Accepted'
GROUP BY State, Name, MONTH(Date)

Comment: @Max Close, but then I only get the results on that month. so for example, April has 2 records. May get 1 record. The state of the ones in April haven't changed and neither has the date, but May should still show that it counts 3 records. The one of its month and the 2 of April. June add another 2 records but one record from April gets accepted. So June counts 4 records ( 1 from April that hasn't been accepted yet, 1 for May and 2 from June). If I group by month, I'm missing that check

Comment: Aha alright. I can't quickly think of a way to solve that problem for you and I don't have the time to work it out with some test data. I suggest you change your question so it is more clear to everyone (Spelling and grammar), maybe other can help you further.

Comment: Why is #records=5 for DPK/April/Withdrawn? I see in Table1 only ID 2 and 3 for DPK